# How to use SSL certificate in java http client to make request to server

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keytool, truststore

I have a .crt file provided by some thirdparty. Now i have to call their API over TLS. Can someone tell me how to use this .crt in java code to make secure call. I am using windows machine and java 8

Comment: you've provided too few information - is the CRT file a public certificate of the server hostname? If so, you may want to import the crt into your truststore. I recommend mendling with the default JRE truststure, you may create your own, however ho to use it depends on the library / framework you want to use to call the API

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You need a key pair, produced by you, and a certificate, signed either by a third party in response to a CSR generated by you, or a self-signed certificate generated by you that the server trusts.

Or else you don't need the certificate at all, unless it is untrusted, which you don't state.

Comment: maybe he wants to call the the API as a client, not exposing API as a server. So the client doesn't need any keypair / certificate to call a service